# почему игнорируется cin при последующих итерациях цикла?

Tags: c++

```
bool check = false;
while (!check) {
    cin >> range;
    if (!cin) {
        cout << "Discrepancy of data types or ranges, repeat enter" << endl;
    }
    else check = true;
}
```

Comment: Какого типа `range`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если все считано верно, `if (!cin)` дает `false`, и вы выходите из цикла.

Если нет и установлен бит ошибки - то вы возвращаетесь в цикл, и пытаетесь читать из потока *в состоянии ошибки*, а в этом состоянии все действия игнорируются...

Вам надо сбросить бит ошибки `cin.clear()` и сбросить входной буфер

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

и только после этого пытаться читать заново.

Comment: спасибо 
попробую
просто пробовал 
cin.clear();
cin.sync();

Comment: большое спасибо